# Find average values of a column in terms of date range of another column in R

Tags: r, date, average, na

I have two data frames that look like this:

```
> head(y,n=4)
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]

  Start Date   End Date   Length

1 2006-06-08 2006-06-10        3
2 2006-06-12 2006-06-14        3
3 2006-06-18 2006-06-21        4
4 2006-06-24 2006-06-25        2
```

and

```
> head(x,n=19)
          Date   Group.Size
413 2006-06-07            6
414 2006-06-08            3
415 2006-06-09            1
416 2006-06-10            3
417 2006-06-11            15
418 2006-06-12            12
419 2006-06-13            NA
420 2006-06-14            4
421 2006-06-15            8
422 2006-06-16            3
423 2006-06-17            1
424 2006-06-18            3
425 2006-06-19            10
426 2006-06-20            2
427 2006-06-21            7
428 2006-06-22            6
429 2006-06-23            2
430 2006-06-24            1
431 2006-06-25            0
```

I'm looking for a way to add a new column in data frame y that will show the average Group.Size of data frame x (rounded to nearest integer), depending on the given Start Date and End Dates provided in y.

For example, in the first row of y, I have 6/8/06 to 6/10/06.  This is a length of 3 days, so I would want the new column to have the number 2, because the corresponding Group.Size values are 3, 1, and 3 for the respective days in data frame x (mean=2.33, rounded to nearest integer is 2).

If there is an NA in my dataframe x, I'd like to consider it a 0.

There are multiple steps involved in this task, and there is probably a straightforward approach... I am relatively new to R, and am having a hard time breaking it down.  Please let me know if I should clarify my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `x$Date`, `y$StartDate`, and `y$EndDate` are of class `Date` (or, `character`), the following `apply` approach should be doing the trick:

```
 y$AvGroupSize<- apply(y, 1, function(z) {
                 round(mean(x$Group.Size[which(x$Date >= z[1] & x$Date <=z[2])], na.rm=T),0)
    }
)
```

Comment: Exactly. I noticed and did the necessary amendment. Thank you.

Comment: This works beautifully. Do you mind walking through your steps?  I'm trying to walk through what you did with function(z). @submartingale

Comment: This won't treat `NA` as zero, though.

Comment: @Stibu Yes, you are right. It ignores NAs instead of replacing them with 0s. Treating NAs as 0 is straightforward by adding a line at top: `x$Group.Size<-x$Group.Size[is.na(x$Group.Size)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
#Replace missing values in x with 0
x[is.na(x)] <- 0

#Create new 'Group' variable and loop through x to create groups 
x$Group <-1
j <- 1
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  if(x[i,"Date"]==y[j,"StartDate"]){
    x[i,"Group"] <- j+1
    if(j<nrow(y)){
      j <- j+1
    } else{
      j <- j 
    }
  }else if(i>1){
    x[i,"Group"] <- x[i-1,"Group"]
  }else {
    x[i,"Group"] <- 1
  }
}

#Use tapply function to get the rounded mean of each Group
tapply(x$Group.Size, x$Group, function(z) round(mean(z)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)

na2zero <- function(x) ifelse(is.na(x),0,x) # Convert NA to zero
ydf %>%
    group_by(Start_Date, End_Date) %>%
    mutate(avg = round(mean(na2zero(xdf$Group.Size[ between(xdf$Date, Start_Date, End_Date) ])), 0)) %>%
    ungroup

##   Start_Date   End_Date Length   avg
##       (time)     (time)  (int) (dbl)
## 1 2006-06-08 2006-06-10      3     2
## 2 2006-06-12 2006-06-14      3     5
## 3 2006-06-18 2006-06-21      4     6
## 4 2006-06-24 2006-06-25      2     0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that applies over the rows of the data frame `y`:

```
library(dplyr)
get_mean_size <- function(start, end, length) {
   s <- sum(filter(x, Date >= start, Date <= end)$Group.Size, na.rm = TRUE)
   round(s/length)
}
y$Mean.Size = Map(get_mean_size, y$Start_Date, y$End_Date, y$Length)
y
##   Start_Date   End_Date Length Mean.Size
## 1 2006-06-08 2006-06-10      3         2
## 2 2006-06-12 2006-06-14      3         5
## 3 2006-06-18 2006-06-21      4         6
## 4 2006-06-24 2006-06-25      2         0
```

It uses two functions from the `dplyr` package: `filter()` and `mutate()`.

First I define the function `get_mean_size` that is supposed with the three values from a column in `y`: `Start_Date`, `End_Date` and `length`. It fist selects the relevant rows from `x` using filter and sums up the column `Group.Size`. Using `na.rm = TRUE` tells `sum()` to ignore `NA` values, which is the same as setting them to zero. Then the average is calculated by dividing by `length` and rounding. Note that `round` rounds half to even, thus 0.5 is rounded to 0, while 1.5 is rounded to 2.

This function is then applied to all rows of `y` using `Map()` and added as a new column to `y`.

A final note regarding the dates in `x` and `y`. This solution assumes that the dates are stored as `Date` object. You can check this using, e. g.,

```
is(x$Date, "Date")
```

If they do not have class `Date`, you can convert them using

```
x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date)
```

(and simliarly for `y$Start_Date` and `y$End_Date`).

Comment: My output is correct. The difference between my solution and what you propose is that `mean` with `na.rm = TRUE` will omit the `NA` values when calculating the mean, while the OP asked to treat `NA` as zero. Also, I decided to use `length` since there might be dates missing.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but here is one. We can first create a list of date positions with `lapply` (SN: Be sure that the dates are in chronological order). Then we map the function `round(mean(Group.Size))` to each of the values:

```
lst <- lapply(y[1:2], function(.x) match(.x, x[,"Date"]))
y$avg <- mapply(function(i,j) round(mean(x$Group.Size[i:j], na.rm=TRUE)), lst[[1]],lst[[2]])
y
#    StartDate    EndDate Length avg
# 1 2006-06-08 2006-06-10      3   2
# 2 2006-06-12 2006-06-14      3   8
# 3 2006-06-18 2006-06-21      4   6
# 4 2006-06-24 2006-06-25      2   0
```